# How to sum the elements of N lists?

Tags: python, list, sum, element

can anybody please give me a hint how to aggregate (sum up) specific elements of multiple lists?

For example I have 20 lists with a similar name pattern, each representing consumption spending over time (i.e. index) of the corresponding household (agent):

```
c_agent_0 = [10.0, 11.0, ...]
.
.
.
c_agent_19 = [8.0, 9.0, ...]
```

I need something like value = sum of index whatever's in `c_agent_*[whatever]`

Comment: Can you illustrate your question further with an example, please?

Comment: `c_agent_0` is a massive red flag - If you have a load of variables with numbered names, you want a list instead. Here you could simply have a list of lists.

Answer (score 7):

Use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to "combine" lists into single one, then sum elements for each index:

```
c_agent_0 = [10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0]
c_agent_1 = [1.1, 12.3, 14.2, 13.2, 14.3]
c_agent_2 = [1.4, 12.1, 14.5, 13.1, 14.2]

zipped_list = zip(c_agent_0, c_agent_1, c_agent_2)

print zipped_list
print [sum(item) for item in zipped_list]
```

prints

```
[(10.0, 1.1, 1.4), (11.0, 12.3, 12.1), (12.0, 14.2, 14.5), (13.0, 13.2, 13.1), (14.0, 14.3, 14.2)]

[12.5, 35.4, 40.7, 39.3, 42.5]
```

Comment: *Use zip to combine lists into single one* - That's not really what `zip()` does - you might want to give a better explanation. It transposes the iterable of iterables (the first row becomes the first column, etc...).

Comment: Ok, agreed, thanks. I've just added link to docs, marked combine with quotes, and improved the code example.

Comment: IMHO, Its still misleading to refer to zip as "combining" lists into "single one". That makes it sound like a "merge". I had to read the entire post carefully, to see what is going on. Maybe say something like "*Use zip to make a list of lists, where the first sub-list contains the first element of each original list, etc.*"

Answer (score 4):

You can create a list of lists, and then use numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
c_agent_0 = [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]
c_agent_1 = [13.0, 14.0, 15.0]
c_agent_2 = [16.0, 17.0, 18.0]
mylist = [c_agent_0, c_agent_1, c_agent_2]
mylist = sum(map(np.array, mylist))
print mylist[0]
```

Note that a list comprehension is most likely faster; this is just a solution with numpy :).

Comment: The question is about summing (what are essentially) columns, not just the lists.

Comment: @Lattyware Edited my answer :3

Comment: Thank you so far, the point is that the the number of lists could become large (for example 400 households), so any solution which includes typing the names of the lists is not very convenient. I could not figure out so far how to use the string wildcard * and do the sum for all lists which fits to the name pattern c_agent_*

Comment: @JohnDoe The point is that `mylist` should be constructed without constructing `c_agent_0`, `c_agent_1`, etc... individually. Data structures stop you from having to type out a ton of repetitive code. `mylist = [[10.0, 11.0, ...], [13.0, 14.0, ...], ...]` or if you construct the data another way, then change your code to produce a list of lists.

Comment: @Lattyware: you're right, I have already created mylist with a loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this to *all* the columns, then [alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698685/722121) is best, if you only want a single one (or a subset), then it's a little wasteful as it does a lot of unnecessary processing.

For a single column (the third in this case):

```
sum([c_agent[2] for c_agent in c_agents])
```

We use the `sum()` built in to sum, and a simple [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to get the nth item from each list.

As noted in my comment, this assumes you have a list of lists, as opposed to a load of variables:

```
c_agents = [c_agent_0, c_agent_1, ...]
```

Using data structures effectively will make your code much, much better.

The previously mentioned `zip()` based solution can also easily be modified to work with this data structure:

```
[sum(column) for column in zip(*c_agent_s)]
```

Here we use the `*` operator to unpack the list as the arguments for `zip()`.