# summing elements of multiple dictionary lists with zip

Tags: python, dictionary, zip

I have dictionary keys as defined below:

```
d['abc']=[1,2,3]
d['def']=[2,4,6]

zipped_list_1=zip()
zipped_list_1.append(d['abc'])
zipped_list_1.append(d['def'])

print zipped_list_1
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]]<----I want to get [d['abc'],d['abc']] instead
print [sum(item) for item in zipped_list_1]
[6,12]<------------I want [(3),(6),(9)] instead
```

Here is an example:[Python: Sum of element for n-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698612/python-sum-of-element-for-n-lists) but it doesnt talk about dicts.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: How does what you want to do differ from what you've done?

Comment: The output you say you're getting isn't what you would actually get if you ran that. Please don't post fake output; actually run your code and post the real results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want something like this:

```
d = {}
d['a']=[1,2,3]
d['b']=[2,4,6]

zipped_list = zip(d['a'],d['b'])
print map(lambda x: sum(x), zipped_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're building your `zipped_list_1` will not produce the results you expect. If you're sure the lists that are elements of your dictionary are of equal length, you want something like:

```
zipped_list_1 = zip(*d.values())
print [sum(item) for item in zipped_list_1]
```

`d.values()` returns a list of the elements of your dict - in this case, the sublists, so it evaluates to `[[1,2,3], [2,4,6]]`. The `*` operator then assigns its values as positional parameters to `zip` - for the input you listed it's equivalent to calling `zipped_list_1 = zip([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6])`. That will give you `[[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6]]` in `zipped_list_1`, so the `sum` list comprehension will behave as you expect.

Comment: what if my dictionary has varying lengths of key and value pairs and i only want 2 of the keys to be in zipped_list_1 instead of all they keys in my dictionary?

Comment: If you only want two specific keys, the best way is to pass the specific keys to `zip` as @alcedo's answer shows. There are other techniques if, say, the keys you want are themselves contained in a sequence rather than known beforehand - eg `zip(*(d[key] for key in some_key_sequence))`. But that might be more complicated than you need. For varying lengths - `zip` will truncate to the shortest sequence. If you want to run larger sequences, you can look into the `itertools` built in module and its `izip_longest` function - for summing, using 0 as the extend value should work well.