# Summing multiple lists

Tags: python, list, sum

I have three lists that I'd like to sum.

```
list_1 = (a1 , a2 , a3 , ... , a5184)
list_2 = (b1 , b2 , b3 , ... , b5184)
list_3 = (c1 , c2 , c3 , ... , c5184)
```

I would like to sum them so that the new list I get looks like this:

```
final_list = (a1+b1+c1 , a2+b2+c2 , a3+b3+c3 , ... , a5184+b5184+c5184)
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: @Aidan, before asking a question you should always look for other related questions that exist on StackOverflow. In my answer below I quickly found a similar question. According to S.O rules, it is likely that your question will be "closed" since it is similar to the one already answered( link in my answer)

Comment: Use `zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)` to get tuples `(element1, element2, element3)` and then use `sum` to add those up. Do this inside a `for` loop (or for more advanced usage, a list comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

From [How to sum the elements of N lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698612/how-to-sum-the-elements-of-n-lists)

```
zipped_list = zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)
final_list = [sum(item) for item in zipped_list]
```

This is the fastest way, to use list comprehensions; otherwise you could use numpy, but it is not necessary as you would have to install it separately.

Comment: If you want a cute one-liner you could do `final_list = list(map(sum, zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)))`

Comment: Nice one David!

Answer (score 0):

Look more into what `zip` does exactly, see this [link](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip).

Try something like this:

```
firstList = [0, 1, 2]
secondList = [3, 4, 5]
thirdList = [6, 7, 8]

finalList = zip(firstList, secondList, thirdList)

print([sum(num) for num in finalList])
```

Output:

```
[9, 12, 15]
```