# Summation of 4 lists gives me a list with lists instead of summing there elements

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I am trying to sum from 4 lists there elements with each other. For a example the first element from fours lists, then the second element etc

But instead of that i am getting a list with nested lists with the four elements and i cannot understand why and how to solve it.Any ideas?

```
#dependency influence calculation
def dep_Influence(a,b,c,d,decimal):
    influence=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
       x=float(a[i])+0,5*float(b[i])+0,33*float(c[i])+0,25*float(d[i])
       influence.append(x)
    influence = np.around(influence,decimal)
    return influence
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum the elements of N lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698612/how-to-sum-the-elements-of-n-lists)

Comment: Not exactly because i multiply each element with a different factor:
x=float(a[i])+0,5*float(b[i])+0,33*float(c[i])+0,25*float(d[i]).

Comment: comma is not a floating point separator... You effectively created a tuple of  `(a[i]+0, 5*b[i]+0, 33*c[i]+0, 25*d[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiplying by float numbers, use points instead of commas to represent those values:

```
def dep_Influence(a,b,c,d,decimal):
    influence=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
       x=float(a[i])+0.5*float(b[i])+0.33*float(c[i])+0.25*float(d[i])
       influence.append(x)
    influence = np.around(influence,decimal)
    return influence
print(dep_Influence([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3],  [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 2))
```

> [2.08 4.16 6.24]